Cloudformation stack has drifted an its on state "Deleted"
I'm currently working with AWS Amplify to deploy changes to my production environment. However, each attempt to deploy ends with the error: "is in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED state". Upon investigating the underlying CloudFormation stack, I discovered there is a drift present, which I suspect is causing the deployment failures.
[Attached screenshot of the drift details]
Given this situation, I have a few questions:
How can I accurately identify and understand the specific resources and properties that have drifted from the original stack configuration?
What are the recommended steps to "undrift" these resources? Is there a way to automatically reconcile the drift, or will manual intervention be required?
In case of manual intervention, could you provide guidance or best practices on safely aligning the drifted resources with their expected configurations without impacting the current production environment?
Any insights or experiences shared on resolving stack drift issues, particularly in the context of AWS Amplify and CloudFormation, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance.


Attach the drift details screenshots properly
